# Como puedo obtener la posicion X y Y del elemento doc.text en jspdf

Tags: angular, typescript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

Estoy intentando obtener la posicion X,Y de la propiedad doc.text()

Ejemplo:

let doc = new jsPDF('p', 'm', 'a4');

\\En esta parte la palabra variables viene de un tipo textarea que el usuario podra escibir lo que sea

doc.text(variable,5,5);

\\En esta parte es texto estatico, y las posiciones_x ,posicion_y es en base al primer doc.text()

doc.text("Hola",posicion_x,posicion_y)

Mi pregunta es como obtengo la posicion de X,Y de mi primer doc.text()?

Answer (score 0):

No encontre una propiedad referente , pero esto solucioono el problema:

```
    var doc = new jsPDF()
    var text = 'This is a text without real content but with 59 characters.'
    
    var lineHeight = doc.getLineHeight(text) / doc.internal.scaleFactor
    var splittedText = doc.splitTextToSize(text, 50)
    var lines = splittedText.length  // splitted text is a string array
    var blockHeight = lines * lineHeight
    var yPos = 10
    var xPos = 10
    doc.text(xPos, yPos, splittedText)
    yPos += blockHeight
    doc.text(xPos, yPos, '----- This text follows the previous text block.')
    yPos += lineHeight
    doc.text(xPos, yPos, '----- LineHeight=' + lineHeight + ' / blockHeight=' + blockHeight)
    yPos += lineHeight
    doc.text(xPos, yPos, '----- doc.internal.scaleFactor = ' + 

doc.internal.scaleFactor)
```